# Is there an extended universe to MTV's "Teen Wolf" series?

Tags: books, comics, teen-wolf

I was wondering if there were any form of extended Universe for *Teen Wolf,* much the way *Buffy the Vampire Slayer* and *Smallville* were continued post-series in Y.A. books, games and comics?

Comment: Don't forget the original movies...

Comment: Doesn't count as an extended universe, as this series was a reboot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was an authorised book set in the same fictional universe.

- *[On Fire: A Teen Wolf Novel](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/12989106)* by Nancy Holder

and a brief (3 part) comic serial.

- [*Teen Wolf: Bite Me*](https://www.comixology.eu/Teen-Wolf-Bite-Me/comics-series/6659?ref=Y29taWMvdmlldy9kZXNrdG9wL2JyZWFkY3J1bWJz)

During the series' run, there was an online viral game website

- [Teen Wolf: The Hunt](https://teenwolf.fandom.com/wiki/Teen_Wolf:_The_Hunt)

Comment: Thank you. Too bad it didn't move on; I thought uit would be much like the Buffy-Werse